# Как совместить JS для тега audio?

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет. Проблема такова что у меня на сайте есть плеер для аудио, стилизованный через css как мне нужно для дизайна. Мне нужно таких плееров неограниченное количество. Я написал js код, но при клонировании плеера воспроизводиться только первый. собственно сам код.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center carousel-cell" style="width: 120px;">
        <div class="row" style="margin-right: 8pt;margin-left: 8pt;width: 100%;margin-top: 8pt;margin-bottom: 8pt;">
            <div class="col" style="padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="width: 100%;height: 100px;background: url('oliver-sjostrom-beach-white-palm.jpg') center / cover no-repeat;border-radius: 50px;border: 5px solid rgb(255,255,255);" onclick="togglePlay()">
                    <p style="font-family: 'Point Semi';color: rgb(255,255,255);text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgb(82,82,82);margin-bottom: 0px;">Музыка</p>
                    <audio id="music" preload="auto" loop>
                        <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&amp;id=1ujLY9bGiYQGo_OOYE5hRJ2lPVpNDVLAS" type="audio/mpeg">
                        </source>
                    </audio>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

````
function togglePlay() {
    return audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
}```
````

Answer (score -1):

```
Код выше - это что, дай бог да разберутся.
```

По js  должно быть что-то вроде этого.

```js
addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const buttonMusik = event.target.closest('.music');

  if (!buttonMusik) { 
    return;
  }
  buttonMusik.paused ? buttonMusik.play() : buttonMusik.pause();
});
```

Когда мы выполняем клик, ищем кнопку на которой существует класс music. Дальше на случай, если не туда нажали, возвращаем результат, тем самым выходим из функции.

В другом случае нашим кнопкам применяем один из возможных методов...

Таким образом код выполнится именно на том элементе, на который мы кликнули и есть класс music.

Comment: "(Я вернул просто объект)" - зачем?

Comment: Просто захотел, а что*?

Comment: Не могли бы Вы перестать писать бред в Ваших ответах?

Comment: Укажите на то место, где именно бред, я попробую исправится. Если я вернул объект, почему сразу бред-то?

Comment: Кому нужен этот возвращенный объект?

Comment: Хорошо, я отредактирую запись.

Comment: Не нужно одолжений. Настаивайте на своем, если считаете себя правым.